# Where should I place the onClickListener on a Custom ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I am making a custom `ListView` of rows containing a `CheckBox` and a `TextView`. Before I used custom `ListViews` with SimpleCursorAdapter, my `onListItemClick()`  worked fine.

I've read I have to add an `onClickListener` to my `TextViews` but WHERE? And WHY?

I am still extending `ListActivity` and passing an `Adapter` to `setListAdapter(listedPuzzleAdapter);`, am I not?

```
public class PuzzleListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private PuzzlesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor puzzlesCursor;

    private ArrayList<ListedPuzzle> listedPuzzles = null;
    private ListedPuzzleAdapter listedPuzzleAdapter;

    private class ListedPuzzleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListedPuzzle> {

        private ArrayList<ListedPuzzle> items;

        public ListedPuzzleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<ListedPuzzle> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.puzzles_row, null);
            }
            ListedPuzzle lp = items.get(position);
            if (lp != null) {
                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitles);
                title.setText(lp.getTitle());
                CheckBox star = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.star_listed);
                star.setChecked(lp.isStarred());
            }
            return v;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.puzzles_list);

        // Create database helper to open connection
        mDbHelper = new PuzzlesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        fetchData();
    }   

    private void fetchData() {
        puzzlesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPuzzles();
        startManagingCursor(puzzlesCursor);

        listedPuzzles = new ArrayList<ListedPuzzle>();
        ListedPuzzle lp;

        puzzlesCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!puzzlesCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            lp = new ListedPuzzle();
            lp.setTitle(puzzlesCursor.getString(puzzlesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            lp.setStarred(puzzlesCursor.getInt(puzzlesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_STARRED)) > 0);
            listedPuzzles.add(lp);
            puzzlesCursor.moveToNext();
        }

        listedPuzzleAdapter = new ListedPuzzleAdapter(this,
                R.layout.puzzles_row, listedPuzzles);
        setListAdapter(listedPuzzleAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PuzzleQuestionActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

EDIT: My question was towards making the whole item of a custom `ListView` clickable so I found the best answer was the one given by @Luksprog. The `onListItemClick` from my `ListActivity` was enough. I just needed to set the `android:focusable='false'` to make it work.

Now, the `CheckBox` on each item of the `ListView` should "star" that item, which means, accesing the DB.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.puzzles_row, null);
            }
            ListedPuzzle lp = items.get(position);
            if (lp != null) {
                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitles);
                title.setText(lp.getTitle());
                CheckBox star = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.star_listed);
                star.setChecked(lp.isStarred());

                star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Integer realPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        ListedPuzzle obj = items.get(realPosition);
                        obj.getId();

                    }

                });
            }
            return v;

        }
```

But the `v.getTag()` refers to a non-final variable and if I change it the `v = vi.inflate(R.layout.puzzles_row, null)` cannot be assigned. 
What's the best way to solve this? I never really understood the whole final deal.

Comment: what you want onlistitem click?

Comment: do you want `TextView` ClickLisner?

Comment: I want to launch another activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a special action for when you click the `TextView` or/and `CheckBox` from any of the rows in your `ListView` then add a `OnCLickListener` for those `Views` in the `getView` method of your custom `Adapter`:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.puzzles_row, null);
            }
            ListedPuzzle lp = items.get(position);
            if (lp != null) {
                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitles);
                //set as the tag the position parameter 
                title.setTag(new Integer(position));                    
                title.setOnclickListener(new OnCLickListener(){

                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do the stuff you want for the case when the row TextView is clicked
                    // you may want to set as the tag for the TextView the position paremeter of the `getView` method and then retrieve it here
                    Integer realPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    // using realPosition , now you know the row where this TextView was clicked
                }
            }); 
                title.setText(lp.getTitle());
                CheckBox star = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.star_listed);
                star.setChecked(lp.isStarred());
            }
            return v;
        }
```

If you want to do an action when a row is clicked(no matter what `View` from that row was clicked(if one was clicked)) just use the `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`(or the callback `onListItemClick` in the case of a `ListActivity`).

Also, I hope you set `android:focusable="false"` for the `CheckBox`(in `R.layout.puzzles_row`) because I don't think `onListItemClick` will work otherwise.

**Edit :**

You start the new `Activity` in the `onListItemClick`(in the case of the `ListActivity`) callback if you want to start the new activity **no matter where the user clicks a row**:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {          
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PuzzleQuestionActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

If, for some reason, you want to start the new `Activity` when the user clicks **only**(for example) the `TextView` in a `ListView` row then start the new activity in the `onClick` method from my code above:

```
//...
title.setOnclickListener(new OnCLickListener(){

                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Integer realPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        ListedPuzzle obj = items.get(realPosition);
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, PuzzleQuestionActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, obj.getTheId());//see below
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
//...
```

For this to work you'll have to modify `ListedPuzzle` to also add the `PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID` column from the `puzzlesCursor` cursor in the `fetchData()` method:

```
//...
while (!puzzlesCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            lp = new ListedPuzzle();
            lp.setTitle(puzzlesCursor.getString(puzzlesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            lp.setStarred(puzzlesCursor.getInt(puzzlesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_STARRED)) > 0);
            lp.setTheId(puzzlesCursor.getLong(puzzlesCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)));
            listedPuzzles.add(lp);
//...
```

Comment: Excellent @Luksprog! Thx a lot. You even anticipated with the checkbox focusable to false, which I couldn't figure out. Still, I dont understand what you mean with setting the tag for the TextView. How do Where do I launch the new activity with my item id?

Comment: @eskalera See my edited answer(also look at my `getView` method code). You put the code to launch the new `Activity` depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thaaaanks so much @Luksprog, Crystal clear this time. Finally got it working. My case was the first one but the the second snippet solved all my doubts. I just had to add `i.putExtra(PuzzlesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id + 1);` since the ArrayList starts at 0 unlike the Cursor.

Comment: I've made a little change reflected on my EDIT above. There's still a little doubt regarding your solution.

Comment: @eskalera You didn't fully understand my answer. You set the `position` as a tag for the `View` on which you also set the listener, so for your `CheckBox`: `star.setTag(new Integer(position));`. In the listener you get a reference to the `View` that was checked, it's the `buttonView` parameter so you do:`Integer realPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();`. You don't have any business with the `v` object(the `final` problem comes because you're trying to access a variable from a anonymous inner class).

Answer (score 2):

you can assign an `onClickListener` in the adapter, but it's bad practice.

what you should do, is to implement `onItemClick` like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    TextView text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // DO SOMETHING or in your case 
    //startActivity(new Intent(<the correct intent>);
}
```

Comment: inside the adapter? in the activity? None have that method.

Comment: do yourself a favore and implement the `onItemClick` and NOT the onCLick. it's designed for lists

Comment: Ouch! Of course! You mean to implement that interface on my adapter. Ok, sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood. `onItemClick` is to be assigned to the list in your main activity. `onClick` is for single elements. and can be assigned in the `getView` but this is **BAD PRACTICE** and should not be done

Comment: @thepoosh: Can you please tell me why it's bad practice? In one row of my listview, I need 2 button. So I HAVE TO implement onClick on each button in the adapter. I know there are problems with this approach, but I don't know any other way to do

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your ListView.

```
ListView lv = getListView();


  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


  });
```

Comment: No, the adapter should provide the data for each item, and that's all. Listening to the events is the work of the listView, so put your item click logic on this object. I've put an example in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick Listner in your adapter only. In your adapter you are returning v which is view kiond of object. Put there your onCLickListener.

e.g. v.setOnCLickListener.

I am keeping in mind that you want to open an activity on click of view. And yes if your ListedPuzzle class is serializable or parcelable you can forward entire object using putextra method of intent from same.

If you are not clear with answer tell me I will provide you samll code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
 lstviewemojis.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
      }
```